# USB driver missing in Win 10

Tags: drivers, keyboard

I accidentally uninstalled the USB driver " Intel(R) 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller - 1C26 "

Now on post I can use keyboard , but as soon as Windows logo appear I have no keyboard and mouse.

Since I cannot access the PC, how do I recover from this?

I cannot get into safe mode, or run system restore since I have no keyboard/ mouse.

Comment: Does the computer have PS/2 ports? If so you could use a PS/2 keyboard/mouse.

Comment: no, PS/2 have stopped working before this happen.

Comment: Do you have a DVD-rom in you machine? Do you have a Windows Recovery CD?

Comment: This would be an interesting question if it required NOT power cycling...

Answer (score 2):

In order to get windows to reinstall a driver you usually have to remove and insert the device again but seeing as it's part of the chipset you can't do that...

- Check if your motherboard has a PS2 port on the back (large green and/or purple circle on the back of the computer). You can then use this to move your mouse and/or keyboard.
- You could see if you can get one of those cheap USB expansion cards which have a few USBs on them and insert it into a PCIe slot inside the computer.
- You could see if you take your hard drive and insert it into another computer and boot from that it. That should go and find the drivers for the new motherboard, you can then re-install the drivers that your missing or if your lucky that motherboard will install them for you (if it has the same chip set).
- Some motherboard will have multiple USB controllers on them, check if your motherboard has this then find the USBs on the motherboard that are controlled by the other controller and plug your keyboard in there.
- See if there are any other ports that could be compatible with a mouse or keyboard. E.g Thunder Port, Fire Wire, etc.
- If all else fails you might have to reinstall windows (worst case).

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Just power cycle the computer.  Windows should reinstall the drivers automatically.

If your power button is set to turn of the computer, you should be good to go - unless you have unsaved documents, then it will wait for a response you cant give.  However, turning your computer off by holding the power button down for 10 seconds will not cause any damage.